# How does the position indicator associated to a file pointer after calling fseek, fwrite and fread changes

Tags: c, file, clang, fwrite, fread

I am working on a program that manipulates registers on a file and stumble upon a very weird problem. When removing records I make an inverse list of available slots in the deleted records to reclaim the space when adding new records.
So when I delete a record I put a special char ('*') to indicate it's deleted and write a -1 after that to indicate it's the last available slot.
Then I go back to the previous last slot and change it's -1 to the offset of the newly deleted record.
Here is my code for doing that:

```
char deleted = '*';
long lastSlot = rh->slotList[rh->slotCount -2];
long newLastSlot = rh->slotList[rh->slotCount -1];
fseek(rh->file, lastSlot, SEEK_SET);
fwrite(&deleted, 1, sizeof(char), rh->file);
fwrite(&newLastSlot, 1, sizeof(long), rh->file);
```

This works fine, but the weird problem is that before I was doing:

```
char deleted;
long lastSlot = rh->slotList[rh->slotCount -2];
long newLastSlot = rh->slotList[rh->slotCount -1];
fseek(rh->file, lastSlot, SEEK_SET);
fread(&deleted, 1, sizeof(char), rh->file);
fwrite(&newLastSlot, 1, sizeof(long), rh->file);
```

And this does NOT work. 
I am not sure exactly what happens, but when I try to read that record again it still has the -1 instead of the value in newLastSlot.

Running on a debugger I can see that deleted get read properly to '*' and newLastSlot also have the right offset on it, but somehow it does not get written properly after the call to fwrite.

Can someone explain to me why this happens? Does fread and fwrite uses a different position indicator or something like that?
By the way, I am opening the file with "rb+" and using clang

Comment: From [`fopen()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=vs-2019): *However, when you switch from reading to writing, the input operation must encounter an EOF marker. If there is no EOF, you must use an intervening call to a file positioning function. The file positioning functions are fsetpos, fseek, and rewind. When you switch from writing to reading, you must use an intervening call to either fflush or to a file positioning function.*

Comment: Nice, thank you. My bad for missing that.